# how to define a path to save a log file in log4j

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I created a simple java web application with tomcat as a server. I want to log all the error messages. I am using log4j.

In log4j.properties I stated

```
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\messages.log
```

I might be moving my war file to linux / mac. So I want to store it in my project/logs folder. how can I set that path ?

Answer (score 0):

You can user tomcat system variables and e.g. store all logs in tomcat logs folder:

```
log4j.appender.serverlog.File=${catalina.base}/logs/my-application.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java system properties for this.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/project.log
```

If you want a specific folder, you can set a property to use.

```
JAVA_OPTS='$JAVA_OPTS -Dmy_log_folder="/var/myapp/log';
catalina start
```

And in your log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${my_log_folder}/project.log
```